# Simulating a click to submit a form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Alright so I have a text field that will have a bar code scanned into said text field. It will search the database and return information in the form of a submit button. I am using this code to simulate a click on the submit button.

```
if($.browser.msie){
//simulate a click on the button
    $("#search").keyup(function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          $('input:submit').click();
        }
     });
}
```

The problem with this code is that it takes all of the keystrokes and then clicks the button that many times. This submit will represent data that gets written into the database, so if the bar code was abc123 it would do this action 6 times, but I just need it to do it once. How do I fix this? My code works in FF and Chrome, but not IE, which is the one I need to get this to work in. Grrr I hate IE so much!

Comment: Should the browser not submit the form on enter by default, without any additional JavaScript?

Comment: If your bar code reader simulates pressing the enter key after entering the bar code into your input field, does it not automatically trigger your form's default submit action?

Comment: This is what I thought as well, but it doesn't work in IE for some reason, probably because IE sucks, but I cant tell for sure ;)

Comment: How would that submit 6 times? Are you sure you are not cached with a different file without the enter key check.

Comment: @epascarello: If I were cached with another file wouldn't I also see the same results in FF and Chrome?

Comment: Apparently I'm an idiot, I didn't realize this, but I was already doing the above code was embedded in a function looking for a keyup in the search field. All i had to do was remove the keyup in the code above and look for the event code of the keyup and it works beautifully now. Thanks for the help, and the time taken to answer something I wasn't even providing. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to "click" that submit button? Why don't you just submit the form like:

```
$("#search").blur(function(){
   document.myform.submit();
});
```

Your barcode reader will do this for you.

Comment: I was informed that what the barcode reader does is like typing everything in a half second and then hitting enter, so I figured I had to force it to happen in IE by simulating a click, but this method above doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get code like this:

```
var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
```